# Compound Looping a code

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

#### Ignore! I apologize I realized python uses for x in range() for its while loops

```
#Point Calc System

from random import randint
        team1 = 0
        team2 = 0
        winloss = 0
        check = 0
        x = 0
        i = 0

  #while x < 6:  - Didnt work, probably formatting issue -
        #x += 1
        #Runs best of 3 games
        while i < 3:
            i = i + 1
                
            #2 = win // 1 = loss
            winloss = randint(1,2)
            check = check + winloss
            print("Check = ",check)
                
            if winloss == 2:
                team1 = team1 + 2
                print("win ",team1)
            else:
                team2 = team2 + 2
                print("loss ",team2)
                
        #Test to see if a Team won 2/3 battles or won 2 in a row.
        if team1 > team2 and check == 5:
            team1 = team1 + 2
            print("team1 wins",team1)
            
        elif team1 > team2 and check == 6:
            print("Team1 wins no add",team1)
            
        elif team2 > team1 and check == 4:
            team2 = team2 + 2
            print("team2 wins",team2)
            
        elif team2 > team1 and check == 3:
            print("Team2 wins no add",team2)
            
        else:
            #Should never be seen.
            print("error")
```

I thought adding another while loop over top would have worked but it did not, adding a simple:               while x < 6: x+=1... didnt work.

Comment: Do you really need a class for this code?

Comment: Where are you updating x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you had an Indentation Error.

If you run Python in a terminal with spaces in front of your code

```
>>>   x = 1 
File "<stdin>", line 1
    x =5
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

This one execute with no issue

```
>>>x = 1
```

With that said, the below code executes with no issue after getting rid of the incorrect spaces.

```
#Point Calc System

from random import randint
team1 = 0
team2 = 0
winloss = 0
check = 0
x = 0
i = 0
while x < 6:
    x += 1
    #Runs best of 3 games
    while i < 3:
        i = i + 1
        #2 = win // 1 = loss
        winloss = randint(1,2)
        check = check + winloss
        print("Check = ",check)

        if winloss == 2:
            team1 = team1 + 2
            print("win ",team1)
        else:
            team2 = team2 + 2
            print("loss ",team2)

    #Test to see if a Team won 2/3 battles or won 2 in a row.
    if team1 > team2 and check == 5:
        team1 = team1 + 2
        print("team1 wins",team1)

    elif team1 > team2 and check == 6:
        print("Team1 wins no add",team1)

    elif team2 > team1 and check == 4:
        team2 = team2 + 2
        print("team2 wins",team2)

    elif team2 > team1 and check == 3:
        print("Team2 wins no add",team2)

    else:
        #Should never be seen.
        print("error")
```

#### Note : Also remember to not mix tab and spaces (in your indentation inside a while loop or if/else statement)

Comment: Thanks, the main issue was the while loop... using: for x in range(0,6) did the trick the while loops messed with the indentation as you said.